# definition of covariant derivative (along curve)

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, connections

An affine connection on a smooth manifold $M$ is a map $\nabla: \mathcal{V}(M) \times \mathcal{V}(M) \to \mathcal{V}(M)$ satisfying several properties, where $\mathcal{V}(M)$ denotes the set of smooth vector fields on $M$. Now one can show that $\nabla_X Y(p)$ only depends on $X(p)$ and $Y$ on some neighborhood of $p$.

Then when defining the covariant derivative along a curve $\gamma: I \to M$ one requires that $\frac{D}{dt} V(t) = \nabla_{\dot c(t)} V$ holds for vector fields $V$ along $\gamma$ that are extendable to some neighborhood of $c(t)\subset M$.

The right hand side of the expression gets justified by the fact that the connection depends on the first argument only in the point. I don't understand, why we don't need that $\dot c(t)$ is extenable to some neighborhood of $c(t)$ as well.

A consecutive question would be: why don't we define it for rough sections of $TM$, if only points matter?

Comment: Did you try to write down the proof? You just need to show this expression is tensorial in $X$ (meaning it's linear and $\nabla_{fX} Y = f \nabla_X Y$). We don't use bad sections for $X$ because there's no clear value in doing so. Better, if you want $\nabla_{X} Y$ to be a smooth vector field on the curve (you do), then $X$ had better be smooth along the curve.

Comment: $\dot c (t)$ is extendable to some neighbourhood of $c(t)$ (for example by the local vector field with constant components with respect to the local frame coming from some chart). The point is, no matter how you choose the extension $X$, $\nabla_{X(p)} V$ stays the same.

Comment: The important point is that since the derivative depends only on $\dot c(t)$ at this one single time, we simply need to extend a single vector (which can always be done) - there's no need to extend the whole vector field $\dot c(t)$ on an open set (which is not always possible if e.g. $c(t)$ is a self-intersection).

Comment: I am convinced ;)